# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in C (with GMP lib)

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, gmp

I declare mpz variables and initialise them in a void function.

It's not working.

For example:

```
mpz_t a;
init();
   ...
void init(){
   mpz_init(a);
   ....
 }
```

No error.

```
 init();
     ...
    void init(){
      mpz_t a;
      mpz_init(a);
    }
```

An error occurs.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And have you tried running in a debugger to catch the crash in action and see where it happens in your code?

Comment: Any time "an error occurs" it's important to know exactly what the error message _says_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the little bit of code you have, the difference seems to be the scope of the variable `a`. What is the point of calling `mpz_init(a)` on a variable with only local scope (within your `init()` function)? After `init()` returns, `a` disappears. If you need it for anything else later, the variable `a`, and presumably some of the side effects from `mpz_init()`, won't exist. If you want the side effects of `mpz_init()` to persist past the end of `init()`, it must take effect on some structure that also persists past the end of `init()`. In your first example, `a` is declared with global scope, so it persists for the entirety of your program.